# Does ingress have offline mode?

Tags: ingress

I just gotten Ingress for 2 minutes now and already i'm facing a problem. I'm a pre-paid user and that means i don't have internet where i go except for Wi-fi locations.

I was thinking that Ingress was a GPS bounded game.

Is it possible for pre-paid players to play in offline mode or does it require a internet sources wherever you walk?

Comment: There are some portals near Wi-Fi (e.g. a public library is often a portal), but other than those you're out of luck without a mobile data plan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does require you to be online BECAUSE it is GPS bound AND the system needs to verify that you are actually near the portals you are working with - in real time.

For that it needs to read your GPS signal and transfer it to the game servers. Further, once you interact on the same portal as someone from the opposition in real time, the game needs to be aware of that. An offline mode would not allow this.

If an offline mode would be working, you would be able to cheat the game by just pretending to be in a certain location.

Comment: Sounds realistic yes. Damn, that means i can't play this game :-( Too bad they didnt think of pre-paid users.

Comment: @Ladineko I think the issue is that the game was meant for real-time real-world interaction - so by definition offline users are out of the equation.

Comment: Interaction is the key. "Offline mode" and "GPS required" however are not at all mutually exclusive, nor does the online requirement prevent cheating.

Comment: This answer is a little misleading. GPS bound does not preclude offline mode. Google Maps app works great in offline mode with the GPS. The issue is that when you interact with a portal you need to be able to communicate that information to the servers. If you don't have data you can't communicate.

Comment: @Ian true. If you do not read the second line of the answer, the first line is misleading.

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs true, the online mode does not prevent cheating, but I never claimed that. I simply simply concluded that offline mode would not allow the app to verify your location, and thus, if offline was allowed, you would need to enter the location yourself. And then, cheating would be very easy. The reverse however, as you said, does not prevent cheating 100%.

Comment: @uncovery: GPS doesn't use an internet connection; your phone can tell where you are without internet access.

Comment: @me_and I know that. But Ingress cannot check where I am to allow me to hack a portal without internet access - as I wrote.

Comment: Well, you can use other map applications to navigate to portals. I am trying to get Portal locations only to work in ViewRanger. Its completly offline map (or download when in Wifi) then use with no internet at all. Only at the place using GPRS even, you turn on Ingress, hack or whatever.

Answer (score -3):

Offline mode is totaly doable...

Just that when you "re-connect to the server" it approve or reject the data you are trying to upload..

IE- if i created portal and hack a bunch walking around all day, then when  i get home i upload and hope for most of my work to be approved as if it happened at the time!

Basically same as the new tekken7 dual-left-fighter-feature (the pc do the work as if)

Comment: That's not true at all. The game does a lot of checks in real time, and you could not simply send the data to the server afterwards.

Comment: That could work for hacking, but not attacking or linking.

Comment: No, this is the wrong approach. Its interesting but liable to allot of cheating.